# Arrange 52 cards into 4 piles. How many combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm doing some statistical physics and there is a conceptual question involved that I have a poor understanding of how to approach conceptually:
[image]

Any help appreciated :)
Thank You! :)

EDIT: Answer below. In hindsight, it was a silly question. I just didn't think about it hard enough and tried a stupid brute force approach which came out very weird. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every card has four options or four piles to go to, 
So by Multiplication Theorem $4\times4\times4\times4\times4\times....(\text{52 times})=4^{52}$.